# Loss of net access seemingly due to WiFi signal clash with repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, router, signal, repeater, ssid

The apartment I live in has a single corridor opening into rooms A,B,C,D adjacent to each other. The WAN ethernet terminates in room C where I have a Netgear WGR614v7 router installed. This router has a hidden SSID broadcasting on Channel 2 in g band only. The laptop in room D with a 802.11n adapter can see the router clearly. So far so good.

In come a couple of new mobile devices, mostly used in room A. The signal is very weak so I get an Asus RT-N12 b/g/n router, place it in A, and set it up as a wireless repeater via the switch at the back. So the devices in room A are happy. However, the laptop now starts intermittently losing net connectivity but not the WiFi signal. In the connections list, the connected SSID shows radio properties as '802.11gn' which leads me to believe that the laptop is connecting to the router in A, despite the g router being nearer, and that results in some signal confusion. Switching off the 'A' router resolves the issue.

How can I make use of the repeater and yet avoid this problem? The laptop is using Win7/32.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your laptop thinks it is getting a better signal to the wireless repeater, even though it is closer to the router.

If that is the case, your router probably isn't doing you much good anyway. From what you've said, it sounds like your repeater is wired (via ethernet) to your router - if that is the case, disable the wireless capabilities on the Netgear device, and just use the Asus repeater to broadcast your wireless.

If that works and gets you wireless in every room, that is probably the easier solution.

Comment: The two routers aren't (and can't be) wired to each other.